# Can't extract diagonals as vectors in a tridiagonal matrix solver

Tags: fortran, linear-algebra

I'm trying to code the Thomas Algorithm for solving tridiagonal matrix problems of the form `AX=b` where `A` is a tridiagonal matrix, `X` is the unknown vector, and `b` the independent terms vector.

When I try to extract the main diagonal `A(i,i)`, the right and left diagonals `A(i,i+1)` and `A(i,i-1)`, the program fails to do so. What is REALLY awkward is that if I put  `print *,` in the middle of the do loop, it works.

I know it is not strictly necessary to get the diagonals in separate vectors, but I'm trying to do it as explicit as possible for explanatory purposes.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance

Here's the subroutine that solves for the vector X (AM is the matrix)

```
subroutine LU(N,AM,D,X)
implicit none
integer(kind=4) i,N
real(kind=4),dimension(N,N) :: AM
real(kind=4),dimension(N) :: G,X,D
real(kind=4),dimension(N) :: A,B,C,L,U

A(1)=AM(1,1)
B(1)=AM(1,2)
C(1)=0
A(N)=AM(N,N)
B(N)=0
C(N)=AM(N,N-1)

L(1)=A(1)
U(1)=B(1)/A(1)
G(1)=D(1)/L(1)

do i=2,N-1,+1
    C(i)=AM(i,i-1)
    A(i)=AM(i,i)
    print *,      !THIS IS THE "MAGICAL" print *,. REMOVE IT AND IT WON`T WORK
    B(i)=AM(i,i+1)

    L(i)=A(i)-C(i)*U(i-1)
    U(i)=B(i)/L(i)
    G(i)=(D(i)-C(i)*G(i-1))/L(i)
end do

i=N

L(i)=A(i)-C(i)*U(i-1)
U(i)=B(i)/L(i)
G(i)=(D(i)-C(i)*G(i-1))/L(i)

X(N)=G(N)

do i=N-1,1,-1
    X(i)=G(i)-U(i)*X(i+1)
end do

end subroutine LU
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean "the program fails to do so"?? I used -0.5 for the off-diagonals & +1 for the diagonal of `AM` and then `d=(/0.9, 1.1, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5/)` and received `5.7000003       9.6000004       11.300000       10.400000       6.6999998` as output with and without the `print` statement. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and using gfortran 4.6.3

Comment: If inserting an unnecessary `print` statement 'fixes' a problem then there is something seriously wrong with the code, possibly accessing an element outside the bounds of an array. I can't immediately see an error with the code's array indexing but I suggest your recompile and rerun with array-bounds checking switched on -- check your compiler's documentation for how to do this.

Comment: Looking again at your code shouldn't vectors `B` and `C`, which I understand to be the off-main-diagonals, have size `N-1` ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I think that he is assigning `C(1)` and `B(N)` to `0` for this reason, so only `N-1` elements of each are actually used.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the error using ifort 12.0 or gfortran 4.8.1. Which compiler/version are you using?

I also checked your routine against LAPACK, and it is working as expected!

```
subroutine LU_lapack(A, b, x, stat)
  implicit none
  ! Arguments
  real(kind=4),intent(inout) :: A(:,:)
  real(kind=4),intent(in)    :: b(:,:)
  real(kind=4),intent(out)   :: x(:,:)
  integer,intent(out)             :: stat
  ! Local variables
  integer, allocatable            :: IPIV(:) ! Pivot indices for LAPACK
  integer                         :: N, NRHS

  x = b

  allocate( IPIV(size(x,1)),stat=stat )
  if (stat.ne.0) stop 'solve_LU_double: Cannot allocate memory!'

  N    = size(b,1)
  NRHS = size(b,2)

  ! Perform the LU-decomposition
  call SGETRF(N,N,A,N,IPIV,stat)
  if ( stat.ne.0 ) then
    deallocate(IPIV)
    return
  endif

  ! Solve system
  call SGETRS( 'N', N, NRHS, A, N, IPIV, x, N, stat )

  deallocate(IPIV)
end subroutine
```

From the strange behavior you reported I guess there is something wrong before you call your routine - maybe a crossed boundary or a misplaced pointer...
You should run your code through valgrind to find such anomalies!

EDIT: As mentioned earlier in one of the posts, using compiler flags to check for array boundaries etc. might also help to locate the problem... Try that first, it usually is much faster! For gfortran I typically use

```
gfortran -g -fimplicit-none -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow \
         -fbounds-check -Wall -Wextra
```

For ifort I use

```
ifort -g -check noarg_temp_created -implicitnone -fpe0
```